# Is there a way to asynchronously wait for a key in redis?

Tags: python, asynchronous, redis, async-await, python-asyncio

Is it possible to asynchronously wait until some key exists in redis?

My current idea below

```
import asyncio


red = connect_to_redis()

def get_value(key)
    res = None
    for _ in range(100):
        if red.exists(key):
            res = red.get(key)
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return res
```

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Look up how to build a "listener".

Comment: You can use notifications https://redis.io/topics/notifications for this

Answer (score 1):

you can use next code

```
from redis import asyncio as aioredis

cache = aioredis.from_url(url)
value =  await cache.get(key)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @moken it's obvious, no need for an explanation for this code

Comment: @27px Maybe it isn't so obvious which is why the answer was marked as a "low quality answer" and potentially could have been deleted. Hence the comment to prompt the author to consider reviewing the the content to improve the quality. And no I wasn't the one who marked it as low quality.

Comment: This does not answer OPs question - if the key doesn't exist, this will not _wait_ until it does, but immediately return `None`.